# Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.3.1+ and MPC 0.8.0+

Tags: gcc, gmp, mpfr, mpc

I downloaded GCC 4.5 from http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.5.0/ but when I try to setup / build I am getting below error:

```
Linux:>~/shared_scripts/bin/gcc/gcc-4.5.0 1040> /x/home/prakash_satya/shared_scripts/bin/gcc/gcc-4.5.0/configure CC="gcc -m64" --prefix=/x/home/prakash_satya/shared_scripts/bin/gcc/gcc-4.5.0 --with-gmp-lib=/usr/lib64 --with-mpfr-lib=/usr/lib64 --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gcc... gcc -m64
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -m64 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -m64 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for the correct version of gmp.h... no
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.3.1+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
their locations.  Source code for these libraries can be found at
their respective hosting sites as well as at
ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/.  See also
http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html for additional info.  If
you obtained GMP, MPFR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package,
make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header
files.  They may be located in separate packages.
Linux:>~/shared_scripts/bin/gcc/gcc-4.5.0 1041>
```

The following libs are present in respective directories

```
/usr/lib/libgmp.a
/usr/lib64/libgmp.a

/usr/lib/libmpfr.a
/usr/lib64/libmpfr.a
```

I do not have libmpc.a library installed anywhere in boxes.

Based upon the error how can I know :

a) what is the current version of libgmp.a and libmpfr.a are installed.

b) If they are of incorrect version how can I deploy my own version without disturbing the current one?

Comment: try running `./contrib/download_prerequisites.sh` from the gcc source dir. It worked for me (for the current version of gcc though (`gcc-4.7`)

Comment: The script no longer seems to have an .sh extension: `./contrib/download_prerequisites`.

Comment: download_prerequisites.sh was added in 4.6 it looks like. 4.5.0 doesn't have it.

Comment: ./contrib/download_prerequisites works for gcc-4.8.5 as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the directory where I have those libraries installed (`/usr/gnu64/lib`), I also have a `libgmp.la` file (and `libmpc.la` and `libmpfr.la` files), which contain readable text.  The SO version information is in there, but that is not quite the same as the 'product version'.  It tells about link compatibility instead.

I was trying to investigate which version I had, and the weird solution I came up with was to run the GCC (4.6.1) that I built with the `-v` option.  In part, it said:

```
GNU C (GCC) version 4.6.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.1, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 3.0.0, MPC version 0.8.2
warning: GMP header version 5.0.1 differs from library version 5.0.2.
warning: MPFR header version 3.0.0 differs from library version 3.1.0.
warning: MPC header version 0.8.2 differs from library version 0.9.
```

So, it appears that I have GMP 5.0.2 installed (but I built GCC with 5.0.1), and MPFR 3.1.0 (but I built GCC with 3.0.0) and MPC 0.9 (but I built GCC with 0.8.2).  The mismatch comes about because I tried to compile and install GCC 4.6.2 and it presumably needed the newer versions.  (I didn't succeed, but that's a different story.)

I install my custom-built libraries in `/usr/gnu64/lib`, and then tell GCC that's where to find them with the configure options `--with-mpfr=/usr/gnu64/lib`, `--with-gmp=/usr/gnu64/lib`, `--with-mpc=/usr/gnu/64/lib`.  These paths are hard-wired into GCC and it works from there.

Comment: I tried the same step but copying .a and .la to a local folder using --with-gmp/mpfr to local folder but it stills give the same error. Also I downloaded and build gmp/mpfr/mpc from ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/ [gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2,mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2,mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz] but building mpc states - configure: error: GMP version >= 4.2 required while gcc still staes the same error.

Comment: @Prakash: in that case, assume GCC and its configuration suite knows what it is doing, and get on with compiling and installing the other three libraries.  I've always done it as a separate operation, without reference to GCC (even though GCC triggered the rebuilds).  I believe there may be a way to get GCC to build and install the libraries as it goes - by having the source for GMP, MPFR, MPC in the GCC source tree.  Check the `./configure --help` output for information.

Comment: Since writing this, I've taken to having GCC build the version of GMP, MPFR and MPC along with the compiler.  I now get the source for the current version of the library, and extract it into the top-level directory of the GCC source: gmp-6.0.0, mpfr-3.1.2, etc.  Then I create a symlink for each of them: `ln -s gmp-6.0.0 gmp; ln -s mpfr-3.1.2 mpfr; ln -s mpc-1.0.2 mpc`.  Then I run GCC configure and build, and GCC builds these libraries too.

Answer (score 270):

Inside the gcc directory, do this command:

```
./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

After that script, GMP, MPFR, and MPC will be ready to use. Continue with `./configure`.

Comment: Was trying to install gcc 6.2 on bash on ubuntu on windows, this command worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that. I was stuck on a machine with no `sudo`, and this solved my woes

Comment: One thing to mention: this command must be run in the gcc source root folder, it will download the files under there, if run it in other place, configure still cannot find the correct files.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me even on really old CentOS 4 when I wanted to compile newer GCC there.

Comment: Works for me! (on centos)

Comment: Works for gcc-4.8.5 as well.

Answer (score 76):

I had the same problem trying to install/compile GCC 4.8.1. Here is how I solved:

In Debian, just run this two commands:

```
apt-get install libmpc-dev
./configure
```

Comment: On Amazon Linux, it's `sudo yum install libmpc-devel`

Comment: Centos also needs `sudo yum install libmpc-devel`

Comment: On ubuntu 16 it is sudo apt-get install libmpc-dev

Comment: On Raspbian 9.13 there isn't such thing as libmpc-dev

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem compiling GCC 4.9 branch.

For **Red Hat** and **Fedora** based systems, run the following command:

`sudo yum install  gmp  gmp-devel  mpfr  mpfr-devel  libmpc  libmpc-devel`

This will install the GNU multiple-precision (MP) libraries for integer, floating point, and complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Centos7: sudo yum install libmpc-devel

Comment: Good on you for providing an answer . FYI rather than just give an answer It would be helpful to others to tell why you would want to run that command and what it should do. It is also a good idea to ensure that you answer all of the question that is asked

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the base_url in **contrib/download_prerequisites** to base_url='gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/'. Then just follow the steps from the gcc website.  This worked beautifully. Hope this helpes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The other comment answers this question much better.  Your answer should be deleted. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38460654/1935655