# Error in installing latest gcc in centos 6.8

Tags: gcc, centos, lib, centos6.8

I have followed [HDJEMAI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327805/how-to-install-gcc-5-3-with-yum-on-centos-7-2) suggestion, but when I do

```
./configure --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
```

there is this error:

```
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
their locations.  Source code for these libraries can be found at
their respective hosting sites as well as at
ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/.  See also
http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html for additional info.  If
you obtained GMP, MPFR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package,
make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header
files.  They may be located in separate packages.
```

but then if I do

```
sudo yum install libmpc-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, nvidia, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos-tx.psychz.net
 * elrepo: repos.dfw.lax-noc.com
 * extras: mirrors.thaidns.co.th
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirror.mojohost.com
No package libmpc-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

If I look fo the libraries, I have

```
ls /usr/lib64/libmp
libmpcdec.so.5        libmpfr.so.1.2.0      libmpssconfig.so
libmpcdec.so.5.0.2    libmp.so              libmpssconfig.so.0
libmpfr.so            libmp.so.3            libmpssconfig.so.0.1
libmpfr.so.1          libmp.so.3.1.14
```

but notice that there is no `libmpfr.a` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253695/building-gcc-requires-gmp-4-2-mpfr-2-3-1-and-mpc-0-8-0). In that same dirrectory I have `libgmp.so`.

How do I install `libmpc-devel`? And then how do I install gcc?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `contrib/download_prerequisites` in the GCC source directory to download the sources of the dependencies.  GCC will automatically build and use them during the build process.

Matching system libraries on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 are either missing or just too old.

Comment: Thanks, the installation is done. However, I do not know where the executables are. Going to the file `gcc-7.2.0` there is no bin folder and I cannot guess where I can find `gcc`, `g++` and `gfortran`.

Comment: I can see a `gcc` in here `COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/lto-wrapper`, but I suspect that's the `yum` installation, which is the one that I don't want to use.

Comment: Have you already run `make install`? It defaults to a `/usr/local` prefix. The Red Hat repositories do not contain programs in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Yes, I ran `make install`. It ends with something like `Libraries have been installed in: /usr/local/lib/../lib64`. But in `/usr/local/bin` there is just the gcc that I mentioned before. There is nothing on `etc` either.

Comment: So you have installed GCC to `/usr/local`. It's not clear to me why you aren't done after that.