# Installing GMP extention on PHP 7.4 FPM Aplpine (Docker)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having troubble installing the gmp extension on my docker image.
My docker file looks like:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine 

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gmp
```

When I run this docker file I get the error:

```
configure: error: GNU MP Library version 4.2 or greater required.
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gmp' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've tried the solution on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253695/building-gcc-requires-gmp-4-2-mpfr-2-3-1-and-mpc-0-8-0), however it did not work for me.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like the error says: `configure: error: GNU MP Library version 4.2 or greater required.`

You can install GNU MP (`GMP` for short) on Alpine Linux by including the following in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add gmp-dev
```

(or `RUN apt-get install gmp-dev` for other debian distros)

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package gmp-dev` ?! Shouldn't it be `libgmp-dev`?

Comment: this sequence of commands worked out on top of `php:7.4.21-fpm-buster`: 
RUN apt-get install libgmp-dev -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install gmp

Answer (score 9):

I spent half an hour on this, so just to clarify for anyone that is looking for a solution: adding these lines to the Dockerfile for php7.4 worked:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libgmp-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gmp
```